# nested serialize filter output in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In this example:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

this output occurs:

```
'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
'tracks': [
    {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
    {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
    {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
enter code here
```

how Can I define I want just tracks that has orded:1?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
   tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, queryset=Track.objects.filter(order=1))
```

Comment: I did this but it didn't work,it seems queryset section has no effect